# How to make an order of method executions with Retrofit library?

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm working with Retrofit library for a couple of days now and the only main problem I've encountered is how to force a method to be called after all other?
To make things clear:

```
ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<>;
for (String s: test) {
  // do something with Retrofit
  retrofit_method();
}
some_other_method();
```

Unfortunately, `some_other_method()` usually executes **before or in random iteration** of foreach loop. I need to be sure, that `some_other_method()` is executed **after** foreach. How can I do it?

*Upd* I've found a tricky solution (However it works only under certain conditions):

```
// somewhere earlier
int cntr = 0;

ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<>;
for (String s: test) {
  // do something with Retrofit
  retrofit_method();
  cntr++;
  if (cntr == test.size()){
    some_other_method();
    cntr = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: How exactly(or how do you see) does some_other_method() executes before that for each loop runs?

Comment: @Luksprog I write some info in logs. According to this info `some_other_method()` is sent to execution before or while executing loop

Comment: If you're doing things synchronous what you said can't happen. Are you using Retrofit's Callback?

Comment: @Luksprog, yes, I'm using Callbacks, because there're a lot of things to do and UI shouldn't be blocked

Comment: Then you need to monitor every Callback that you set in that for loop and call the method some_other_method() from there(each one) only when all the callbacks have  their success() called.

Comment: You may want to look into RxJava, which provides an easy way to chain asynchronous calls. Retrofit has support for it.

Comment: @corsair992, could you post your comment above as a question so I can accept it? If you don't mind, please, write a brief example. I'm a beginner Android dev(

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't user RxJava myself. If you search around, you'll find some sample code for using it with Retrofit.